# Rule of three with smart pointer?

Tags: c++

I'm a little confused by using "rule of three" with smart pointers. If I have a class whose only data member is a smart pointer, do I need to explicitly define destructor, copy constructor, and assignment operator?

My understanding is that since smart pointer will handle the resource automatically, then I don't need to explicitly define destructor, and thus I shouldn't need to do so for the other two based on rule of three. However, I'm not sure if the default copy constructor is good enough for smart pointers such as shared_ptr.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: EXP0, you better clarify what kind of smart pointer do you use. Is it something like std::auto_ptr, or more like boost::shared_ptr<>?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The default destructor is fine, because the destructor of `shared_ptr` will take care of the deallocation of the object. The default copy constructor *may* be acceptable depending on your purposes: when you copy the object that owns the `shared_ptr`, the copy will share ownership with the original. The same would naturally be true of the default assignment operator. If that’s not what you want, define a copy constructor that does otherwise—for instance, that clones the referenced object.

Comment: You may also want to override the assignment operator.  Move construct/move assign should be fine

Answer (score 5):

In short, "no". The whole point of factoring code into single-responsibility classes is that you can compose your classes from "smart" building blocks so that you don't have to write any code at all.

Consider the following:

```
class Foo
{
  std::shared_ptr<Bar> m_pbar;
  std::string          m_id;
};
```

This class automatically has copy and move constructors and copy and move assignment operators that are as good as they can get, and everything is taken care of.

If you want to be extreme, you could say that in *most* cases you should probably never be writing a destructor or copy constructor *at all* -- and if you do, then perhaps you should best factor that functionality into a separate class with one single responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

The rule of three actually says:

> If you need to define a non-trivial version of any of the following:
>
> 1. Destructor
> 2. Assignment Operator
> 3. Copy Constructor
>
> ...then you probably need the other two as well.

You seem to be interpreting it as:

> If you need a non-trivial destructor then you also need the other two.

But that's not quite the same thing, is it?